# Use value from prompt as highcharts export file name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts, export

Is there any way for me to set the value filled inside a `prompt()` as the filename when exporting from Highcharts?

Click Me!

```js
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
    },
    series: [{
      data: [ 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 ]
    }],
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    } 
  });
});

var f_name;
$('#click').on('click', function() {
  f_name = prompt("Please enter filename name");
  $('#container').highcharts().exportChart();
});
```

Right now, this is what is happening:

[image: Prompt]
[image: On Save]

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noob0605/s1f63u9x/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the filename provide the value in the `filename` property of the settings object you provide to `exportChart()`:

```
$('#click').on('click', function() {
  let f_name = prompt("Please enter filename name");
  $('#container').highcharts().exportChart({
    filename: f_name
  });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cdfhu4Lb/)

See the [HighCharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart%23exportChart#exportChart) for more details.